Reheating beans makes them mushy and unpeeled
I usually cook a large portion of beans and store them in the fridge.
The problem is that when I reheat them they become mushy and the shell starts to peel off.
I usually reheat them by putting them in a small pot, covering them with water but not too much (the water is barely 1 cm more than the beans).
I turn on the heat and when the water starts boiling I turn it a bit down and let it continue with less boil in the pot for 3 mins.
Am I doing it wrong?

Once the beans are at boiling temperature, what is your objective in continuing to cook them?

@Sneftel:I thought I should leave them 2-3 mins but no other objective

You aren't re-heating them, you are cooking them longer, and they are becoming overcooked. If you want to reheat them over the stove use a more gentle heat and keep them on the heat just until they are hot, then take them off. Or, use a microwave.
